# OLEDB ConnectionString for iSeries in C# 5.0 VisualStudio 2012

Tags: .net, sql, ibm-midrange

I need to establish a ConnectionString using OLEDB inside VisualStudio 2012 in C# 5.0
so below is coded:

```
 SQLConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STX;Persist Security Info=False;
  UserID=JG0149;Password=MYPASS;Initial Catalog=LIBJG");
```

The credentials work pretty good on the STX iSeries system

There are many examples using VS 2010 and C# 4.0 but it does not work on C# 5.0 similar to those found in www.connectionstring,com/as-400/

```
SQLConn = new SqlConnection("Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=STX;User Id=JG0149; Password=MYPASS;
Default Collection=LIBJG")
```

but VS2012 does not accept Provider parameter and requests other ones

May someone have a ConnectionString that works in VS2012 to connect into a iSeries to share, please?

Comment: You can't use an ODBC connection? IBM would be the one providing the drivers for an OLEDB connection to an AS400...

Comment: ODBC Connections work pretty good with READ but they have other problems related to the fact that SQLADapter require an indexed table to UPDATE and even th etable is indexed as a view inside iSeries, its SQL is not the same as Microsoft. Similar problems happen with Oracle ODBC. Remember VS2012 and C# 5.0 is new in comparison with ODBC even before Windows XP...

Comment: BTW, the connection thumb rule is the client must provide the connector, in this case Microsoft. Remember the SQL is on the iSeries... Thanks

Comment: If that's truly the rule of thumb then should microsoft provide a connector for every database ever invented? IBM may have a windows client and provide a driver. But its not guaranteed. I was simply suggesting to use ODBC since connecting to an Iseries from windows is usually fraught with problems to begin with...

Comment: And that is what MS did. Only with those that were convenient for them of course. Imagine that you develop a DB and you would need to provide connector for every client exists. Well, that probably will make you loose the interest in.

Comment: ODBC with iSeries works 100% in older environments, including MS (Access, Excel, VB 6 & VFP 9 and of course SSIS). It was always a challenge to make it work with .NET but worked. Now, with OLEDB in VS2012 there is no way to connect and I repeat if you are using DataGrid (a good emulation of iSeries subfiles) with ODBC it is easy to read but not update, as I mentioned before it happens the same with the Oracle ODBC...

Comment: I only need to know if someone has been able to connect C# 5.0 in VS2012 with iSeries using OLEDB. Otherwise, I will need to downgrade to VS2010 to try with it. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you three connection strings that work. I use these in VS2012 to connect to an iSeries V6R1M0.

**Using IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider**:

```
DataSource=*ServerIP*;UserID=*user*;SchemaSearchList="*list of libraries separated by commas*";Database=*database_name*;PersistSecurityInfo=True
```

**Using .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB**

```
Provider=IBMDA400.DataSource.1;Data Source=*ServerIP*;Persist Security Info=True;OLE DB Services=-1;User ID=*user*;Initial Catalog=*database_name*;Catalog Library List="l*ist of libraries separated by commas*"
```

**Connection Used in a WebService**

```
DataSource=*ServerIP*; Default Collection='';User ID=*user*; Password=*password*;Data Compression=True; Connection Timeout = 180;
```

In this last one I don't use **SchemaSearchList** neither **Catalog Library List** because when we establish a connection to iSeries there is one specific Library always present. In that Library we placed a stored procedure, that we always run in every new connection, defining the library list.

I know this question has one year but it's one more help for someone needing.

**Update**

One more thing, IBM Data Provider allows you to establish a connection to DB2 on iSeries whithout any problem but when we talk about Visual Studio integration it's painfull many times.

As an example, until last week I was using the IBM Data Provider that came with the IBM Client Access (client software for iSeries). I could establish sql connections in all my applications, without OLEDB, in Visual Studio 2010 but not in 2012 or 2013.

This was because my Client Access was released prior to VS2012. Last week I've installed an update to Client Access and now I already have sql connections to DB2 iSeries on VS2012 and VS2013. So, it's convenient that you have always the last version of Client Access compatible with your iSeries version.

Also, when you install Client Access check the files machine.config in these folders

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
```

Check for the `DbProviderFactories` tags and all tags inside it. Client Access usually, when installing, leave these malformed.

If possible, for best performance, don't use ODBC or OLE DB when you have a data provider with managed code and optimized by the same company that made the database server. In this case, IBM it's not an exception.

Comment: Rui,
Thank you very much.
I solved the problem in 2013 using the previous solution and it could update the grid without issues (I created the index as suggested). Now I have to work with a new project that extracts data from iSeries and uses dashboards and I will use the connections you provided. 
I just was requested for a WebService solution last week. 
And you are right, someone else would need it also.
Thank you very much again
Jose

Comment: One more thing, IBM Data Provider allows you to establish a connection to DB2 on iSeries whithout any problem but when we talk about Visual Studio integration it's painfull many times.

Answer (score 3):

[SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) is specifically for use with SQL Server.

Use the [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) and related classes for other providers.

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(
        "Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=STX;User Id=JG0149; Password=MYPASS;Default Collection=LIBJG"))
{
    var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT NOW() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1", connection);
    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

I verified the above in Visual Studio 2012 / .NET 4.5.

---

Microsoft seems to be pushing for a return to ODBC and a phasing out of OLE DB.

[SQL Server Blog: Microsoft Aligning with ODBC](https://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2011/08/29/microsoft-aligning-with-odbc.aspx?Redirected=true)

> The marketplace is moving away from OLE DB and towards ODBC, with an eye towards supporting PHP and multi-platform solutions.

[Microsoft SQLNCli team blog: Microsoft is Aligning with ODBC for Native Relational Data Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access.aspx?Redirected=true)

> We encourage you to adopt ODBC in the development of your new and future versions of your application.

Comment: James,
Thank you very much.
Using your response, it worked smoothly at 100%.
I was able to access iSeries and extract data with no issues.
Excellent.
José

P.S.: Related to ODBC, I will read the blogs you sent. I will research even more with the UPDATE issue (requesting an indexed table in iSeries when the file is indexed and even IBM SQL views are created). Thank you again for the information.